# How to use old iPad Mini as smart home dashboard?

Tags: ios, ipad, homekit

I would like to use my old iPad Mini 1 (running iOS 9.3.5) as a dashboard for my smart home, which is managed using Home Assistant.

I've already resolved the first task - how to access Home Assistant from the iPad. It [doesn't work](https://community.home-assistant.io/t/lightweight-ios-version-for-ios-9-3-5/179204/8?u=and7ey) with that old browser, and the app doesn't work either. So, I [run Firefox](https://community.home-assistant.io/t/options-for-lovelace-on-older-ipad-ios-9-3-5/125497/5) on another machine and access it with RealVNC viewer.

I've removed the PIN protection and disabled the automatic screen off. However, I don't want to keep the screen always on.

Now, the question is how to wake it up when someone is around.

I tried to switch the screen on with an external motion detection sensor, but there is no built-in Home application (it is available for iOS 10 only). I am trying other options now, for example, to send a Telegram message with disabled notification, but it seems like it will not help - the screen still requires user to slide to unlock.

What other options should I explore?

Comment: So, basically, you ask whether the "slide to unlock" step can be skipped on a password-less iPad, right?

Comment: @nohillside screen on + slide to unlock